# not able to display with reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am not getting output to this code with reactjs , please tell me what is the problem with this code. I am not able to find the error.i am using react for the first time.

```
<head>
  <script src="https://npmcdn.com/react@15.3.1/dist/react.js"></script>
  <script src="https://npmcdn.com/react-dom@15.3.1/dist/react-dom.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
</body>


<script type="text/jsx">

  var HelloWorld = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
     return <div>
        Hello World
     </div>
    }
  });

  var element = React.createElement(HelloWorld);
  ReactDOM.render(element, document.body);
</script>
```

Comment: Is There any error? try to see browser console

Comment: There is no error. I checked the console too

Answer (score 1):

`<script src="text/jsx">...</script>` [has been deprecated](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/06/12/deprecating-jstransform-and-react-tools.html#jsxtransformer).

You can still use it if you want, by also including the standalone version of Babel in your page:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.14.0/babel.min.js"></script>
```

However, this is pretty slow, and it's really advisable to set up a proper React development environment (perhaps using [this boilerplate](https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate), although I don't have any experience with it).

Also, you may get a warning because you're rendering the component to `<body>`, thereby replacing it. You probably want to render into a separate `<div>`:

```
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script src="text/jsx">
    ...
    ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('app'));
  </script>
</body>
```